# Appending to a .csv file

Tags: files-and-directories, csv-format

I have a selection of `List`s of data which are in the same format, and if I `Export` them all to CSV at the same time I get a nice result which I can then `Import` again to get back the data in the same formats. I also need to be able to append to a previously written file. I have tried a selection of ways of doing this and I cannot get a sensible result. Can somebody show me how?

With `data` in my row format, which is a `List` of `List`s with a specific definition, and `f = OpenAppend[filename <> ".csv"]`,  I have tried things like;

```
Write[f, data];
```

and

```
Write[f, #]&@@data;
```

and

```
Write[f, #]&/@data;
```

and

```
(Write[f, #];WriteString[f,","])&/@data;
```

none of which work.

Solution by J. M. needs help;

```
WriteString[str, "\n"<>ExportString[{{4, d, "D"}}, "CSV"]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = {{1, a, "A"}, {2, b, "B"}, {3, c, "C"}};
Export["data.csv", data];

str = OpenAppend["data.csv"];
WriteString[str, "4,\"d\",\"D\"\n"]
Close[str];

FilePrint["data.csv"]
```

> ```
> 1,"a","A"
> 2,"b","B"
> 3,"c","C"
> 4,"d","D"
> ```

You can use a formatting function, e.g.

```
data2 = {{5, e, "E"}, {6, f, "F"}};

format[{x_, y_, z_}] := StringJoin[
  ToString[x], ",\"", ToString[y], "\",\"", z, "\"\n"]

str = OpenAppend["data.csv"];
WriteString[str, format[#]] & /@ data2;
Close[str];

FilePrint["data.csv"]
```

> ```
> 1,"a","A"
> 2,"b","B"
> 3,"c","C"
> 4,"d","D"
> 5,"e","E"
> 6,"f","F"
> ```

Comment: You could do `WriteString[str, ExportString[{{4, d, "D"}}, "CSV"]]` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions! I think J.M.'s solution is what I was after. It just needs a newline character